# Bizarre mousout on layering issue

Tags: kineticjs

I've come across a layering problem and I can't figure out where the bug is. I first onload an image to a specific imagelayer which is the same size as my stage. I next create a circle into a separate circle layer, with the proper imagelayer.add(image), circlelayer.add(circle), followed by the stage.add(imagelayer), stage.add(circlelayer). This works fine. Now if I try to add mouseover and mouseout events, say with an alert(), I get the following error in firebug on the mouseout event. Has anyone come across a similar problem? Thanks

TypeError: this.targetShape is null

this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseleave', evt, shape);

here is a snippet of my code:

```
function drawImage(imageObj) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 721,
    height: 702 
});

    var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var tagLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var floorImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: imageObj,
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: stage.getWidth(),
          height: stage.getHeight()
        });
        imageLayer.add(floorImg);
        var tagImg = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            radius: 70,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4
          });
        tagImg.on("mouseout touchend", function(){
        alert("HERE")

        }, false);
        tagLayer.add(tagImg);

        stage.add(imageLayer);
        stage.add(tagLayer);
    }

      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
      };

imageObj.src = 'layout_good.png';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scoping issue.

move `var stage` `var imgLayer` `var tagLayer` outside of drawImage function and make it global if possible.